# Max string length using scanf -> ANSI C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, scanf

I have:

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
```

and I want to put into `scanf` pattern so I can control the string length:

```
scanf("%100[^\n]s",sometext)
```

I tried:

```
scanf("%MAX_STR_LEN[^\n]s",sometext)
scanf("%"MAX_STR_LEN"[^\n]s",sometext)
scanf("%",MAX_STR_LEN,"[^\n]s",sometext)
```

And it didn't work. I just want to avoid buffer overflow since "sometext" is allocated with `malloc(MAX_STR_LEN)`...

Any ideas?

Comment: Discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457325/how-to-use-sscanf-correctly-and-safely).

Comment: How can you use `MAX_STR_LEN` within a format string?

Comment: @amulous, since it's strict ANSI C, I don't really have access to real string variable. I need to do: char *somestring and then malloc...

Comment: Probably is too late , but I did this function just to solve that problem. https://github.com/tsw1985/Gscanf

Comment: Aside from the answers here, I want to point out that if you use `"%100s"` the allocation needs to be 101 bytes, so in your example, you need `malloc(MAX_STR_LEN+1)`, or `"%99s"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wasn't happy with any of these solutions, so I researched further, and discovered GNU GCC macro  [stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

which can be used as:

```
#define XSTR(A) STR(A)
#define STR(A) #A
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
scanf("%"XSTR(MAX_STR_LEN)"[^\n]s", sometext)
```

Maybe VS2010 offers something similar?

Comment: This is in the ANSI C standard - it *really should* work with VS 2010. (Given the idiosyncracies of VS, though, I'm not sure.)

Comment: This is the proper answer. To everyone saying "don't use scanf()": this should be enough to avoid buffer overflows as described by OP.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks most IDE and compile-time format string checking.

Answer (score 7):

> I just want to avoid buffer overflow

Then don't use `scanf()`. At all.

If you are scanning lines of text, don't `#define MAX_STR` either. You can haz `LINE_MAX` in `<limits.h>` (if you are targeting POSIX compatible systems):

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

As almost everyone says, it is better to use `fgets(..., stdin)` to handle this problem.

In the following link, I have suggested a safe and correct technique that let you to replace `scanf()` by a safer method, by means of a solid **macro**:

[A macro that safely replaces **scanf()**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18371445/2698605)

The macro I have proposed (working with compatible **C99** compilers) is `safe_scanf()`, as shown in the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define safe_scanf(fmt, maxb, ...) { \
    char buffer[maxb+1] = { [maxb - 1] = '\0' }; \
    fgets(buffer, maxb+1, stdin); \
    if ((buffer[maxb - 1] != '\0') && (buffer[maxb - 1] != '\n')) \
        while(getchar() != '\n') \
           ; \
    sscanf(buffer, fmt, __VA_ARGS__); \
  }

#define MAXBUFF 20     

int main(void) {
   int x; float f;      
   safe_scanf("%d %g", MAXBUFF+1, &x, &f);
   printf("Your input was: x == %d\t\t f == %g",  x, f);
   return 0;
}
```

You would have to **tune** the value of `MAXBUFF` according to your needs...
Although the macro `safe_scanf()` is pretty solid,
there are some weakness in using the macro approach:
Missing type-checking for parameters, missing "return" values (which hardly differs from the "true" `scanf()` function, that returns an **int**, with valuable information for error checking), and so on.
All that problems have solution, but it is part of another topic...

Maybe, the most exact solution is to define a function `my_scanf()` with variable number of parameters, by invoking the `stdarg.h` library, joint to a combination of `fgets()` and `vsscanf()`. Here you have the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int my_scanf(const char* fmt, const unsigned int maxbuff, ...) {
    va_list ptr;
    int ret;

    if (maxbuff <= 0)
       return EOF; /* Bad size for buffer[] */

    char buffer[maxbuff+1];
    buffer[maxbuff-1] = '\0';  /* Quick buffer cleaning... */

    if (fgets(buffer, maxbuff+1, stdin) == NULL)
       return EOF; /* Error detected */
    else {
        if ((buffer[maxbuff-1] != '\n') && (buffer[maxbuff-1] != '\0'))
            /* Condition logically equivalent to:
                   fgets() has not reached an '\n'
            */
            while (getchar() != '\n')
               ; /* "Flushing" stdin... */

        va_start(ptr, maxbuff);
        ret = vsscanf(buffer, fmt, ptr);
        va_end(ptr);
        return ret;
    }    
}

#define MAXBUFF 20
int main(void) {
   int x; 
   float z;
   int scanf_ret = my_scanf("%d %g", MAXBUFF, &x, &z);
   printf("\nTest:\n x == %d\n z == %g\n scanfret == %d", x, z, scanf_ret);
   getchar();   
   return 0;   
}
```

The function my_scanf() has the prototype

```
int my_scanf(const char* fmt, const int maxbuff, ...);
```

It accepts a format string `fmt` that behaves in the same way as any other `scanf()`-like does.
The 2nd parameter is the maximum number of **chars** that will be effectively accepted from the standard input (keyboard).
The return value is an **int**, which is `EOF` if `maxbuff` has no sense, or well some input error happened. If a non-negative value is returned, it is the same that would be returned by the standard functions `sscanf()` or `vsscanf()`.

Inside the function, `maxbuff` is incremented in 1, because `fgets()` makes some room for an additional '\0' character.
Non-positive values of `maxbuff` are immediatelly discarded.
`fgets()` will read a string is read from `stdin` (keyboard) with room for at most `maxbuff` characters, including '\n'.
If the user has entered a very long string, then it will bu truncated, and some kind of "flush" mechanism is necessary in order to discard all the characters to the next '\n' (**ENTER**). If not, the next keyboard reading could have older characters, not desired at all.
The condition for "flushing" is that `fgets()` has not reached '\n' after reading `stdin`.
This is the case if, and only if, `buffer[maxbuff - 1]` is not equal to '\0' nor '\n'.
(**Check it!**)
Finally, an appropiate combination of `stdarg.h` **macros** and the function `vsscanf()` is employed to process the variable list of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend the `fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)` approach.

If you *still* want to use scanf() you can create its format at runtime.

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
char format[2 + sizeof(size_t)*3 + 4 + 1];  // Ugly magic #
sprintf(format, " %%%zu[^\n]", (size_t) MAX_STR_LEN);
scanf(format, sometext);
```

or re-define MAX_STR_LEN to be a string

```
#define MAX_STR_LEN "100"
scanf(" %" MAX_STR_LEN "[^\n]", sometext);
```

Still recommend the `fgets()`.
Note `fgets()` will put leading spaces and the trailing `\n` in your buffer whereas `" %[^\n]"` will not.
BTW: the trailing `s` in your formats is not likely doing what you think.

Answer (score -3):

How about

```
scanf("%.*[^\n]s", MAX_STR_LEN, sometext)
```

Comment: Please, pretty please, ***No!***

Comment: Recommend you re-read `*` usage in `scanf()`.  I am certain you will want to change your post.  In printf() usage, `*` reads an integer for size, but not in `scanf()`.  `*` means "An optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored". A very different function.