# How to access a .txt file from command-line input in C?

Tags: c, command-line

For example, I run my program like:

program.exe < text.txt

I want the program to read from file text.txt. How do I begin doing this?

Comment: Just read from `stdin`.

Comment: You should probably gain sone familiarity with Unix tools and understand what `< text.txt` means by itself first. Hint: you're *redirecting standard input*.

Comment: @yezi3 Can you help community to understand, what you really want to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as this is a textfile, you probably want to read it line by line, so

```
char buf[1024];
while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin))
{
    /* do whatever you need with the line that's in buf here */
}
```

Note your code doesn't know about the file, it just reads from standard input. With `<`, you tell your environment (`CMD` on windows, a shell like e.g. `bash` on *nix) to open that file for you and provide it to your program as the standard input instead of the default, the *controlling terminal*, which would normally just read from the keyboard.

Hint: `1024` is kind of a random pick, most text files don't have lines exceeding 1kb. You might want to modify it to better suit your expected input.

Answer (score 0):

another way to do what you are looking for is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  int c;
  while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) fputc(c, stdout);
  return 0;
}
```

[some more help here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414013/best-way-to-read-stdin-that-may-include-newline)

Comment: Of course, there are a *lot* of ways to read from a stream. Reading line-by-line just seemed the most natural for me if the expected input is a text file. I think the essence of the question comes down to a lack of understanding what exactly `<` does here. For your answer, I'd suggest to explicitly state this is the variant of reading a single character at a time.

Comment: enlightened to the core